# Finding the highest frequency of unique words in a string using perl

Tags: perl

I am writing the script to get and print the highest frequency of unique words in paragraph.

For code - refer the attachment.

[image]

```
my $freq; 
my $word; 
my $textdata = <<"END_MSG"; 
mm mm mm mm kk kk kk kkkk kk To pp pp pp pp pp pp. 
END_MSG

foreach $word ( split ( ' ', lc $textdata) 
{
    $freq{$word}++;
    #print $freq{$word};
    #print "..";
}

use sort 'stable';
my @listing = ( sort { $freq{$b} <=> $freq{$a} } keys %freq)[0..5];
foreach my $word ( @listing ) 
{
    print $freq{$word}." $word\n";
};
```

Output 1:

```
5 pp
4 mm
4 kk
1 pp.
1 to
1 kkkk
```

Output 2:

```
5 pp
4 kk
4 mm
1 pp.
1 to
1 kkkk
```

The words `mm`, `kk` frequency are 4 - but when I am running each time the order varies.

I want the output to remain the same.

How can I sort based such that this is the case?

with regards,
Ram.

Comment: Welcome to SO! No, it's not up to the reader to "refer" to an image of code. It's your task to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add code as an image attachment. It is not good for the question (if I want to test your code I must type it in). Please put code into the question body *as text*. You can use the edit link to put it into the question. If you indent the code by four spaces, Stack Overflow should format it nicely for you.

Comment: The thing about code is - it needs to be runnable. A screenshot isn't runnable. Paste your code into the question. Also - offsite links tend to go dead. So we don't like those here.

Comment: i want the output should constant - dont want to get jumbled at every instance.

Comment: So some sample output would also be relevant to your question. Insert that into the question too.

Comment: Now we've the output, but still not the code which produced it - simply consider that "attached" screen-shot of the code as non-existent, because it will be considered that way by the people you ask.

Comment: I have OCRed your code into the question. Please can you verify it. (And please - just post it directly next time)

Comment: Why do people think that sharing code in an image is a useful thing to do?

Comment: Because they're hung up on graphical highlighting and IDEs that show you code blocks and nesting and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, the problem here is - you are trying to sort two values that have no relative ordering.

Your result is therefore based on the return order from `keys` which is *by definition* random (ish). The two are equivalent as far as `sort` is concerned, so it's irrelevant which way they come out.

If you run `keys %freq` several times, you'll get different key-orders. And because sometimes `kk` will come before `mm` as a result - and because as far as `sort` is concerned, they are identical because they have the same frequency - that's why you get what you do.

So what you need is a secondary sort order, such that this is consistent. Like - for example - sort alphabetically *if* the frequency is the same.

Usefully - we can use the fact that the `<=>` combined with the `||` operator lets you chain conditionals. Because if you do;

```
 $condition1 || $condition2;
```

Condition 1 is returned if "true" - and condition 2 if it's false. `<=>` returns `1`, `0` or `-1`. Only `0` is false here, so you can do:

```
 $a <=> $b || $a cmp $b
```

Or in your case:

```
$freq{$b} <=> $freq{$a} || $a cmp $b
```

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @words = qw ( mm mm mm mm kk kk kk kkkk kk To pp pp pp pp pp pp nn nn ); 
my %freq;
$freq{$_}++ for @words; 
print Dumper \%freq; 

foreach my $word ( sort { $freq{$b} <=> $freq{$a} 
                       ||        $a cmp $b        } keys %freq ) { 
    print "$word => $freq{$word}\n";
}
```

This will sort on frequency first, and *if* there are two with the same frequency - will sort alphanumerically. So `kk => 4` will *always* be ordered before `mm => 4`.

You should also note in your code:

- You're not declaring `%freq` - you should. You should also switch on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` which would have told you about this.
- `use sort 'stable';` doesn't seem to do anything. Which isn't really a surprise, because `sort` is working perfectly.